# How to print textfile with QPrinter

Tags: c++, qt, printing

I have a list of textfiles in a treeview (with QFileSystemModel). If a textfile is selected and a print button is pressed. It should show a print dialog and the file should be printed out. I thought (after reading documentations and examples) it should look like this:

```
void berichtenhistorie::on_printButton_released()
{
     QModelIndex index = ui->treeView->currentIndex();
     QFileSystemModel *model = (QFileSystemModel*)ui->treeView->model();

     QString path = model->filePath(index);
     QString name = model->fileName(index);

     QString dir = path;
     dir.remove(dir.size() - name.size(), name.size());
     QFile file(path);

     if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
     {
         file.close();
         if(file.rename(QString("%1geprint %2").arg(dir, name)))
                 qDebug() << "renamed";
     }
     //all above works correctly

     QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
     printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
     printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
     printer.setPageMargins (15,15,15,15,QPrinter::Millimeter);
     printer.setFullPage(false);
     printer.setOutputFileName(path);
     printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::NativeFormat);
     QPainter painter(&printer);
     painter.end();
}
```

The renaming part (so above all the printing stuff) works as it should, no errors or anything. But I get abunch of errors at the printing error. I thought it was because of the libraries, because im using Qt5.

```
#include <QDirModel>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrintDialog>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrinter>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QFile>
```

Here are the errors:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you are using Qt5, where printing functionality has been placed in separate add on (in Qt4 it is part of QtGui module), see [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtprintsupport/qtprintsupport-module.html). So you have to add to pro file this line:

```
QT += printsupport
```

This will fix your build error, but your code doesn't print yet. You have to use `painter`.

If you are planing to support Qt4 it should be like this

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
    QT += printsupport
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! :) But the application got significantly slower :P